# Problema com forecast no R

Tags: r, regressão

Estou tentando fazer uma previsão do PIB relativamente simples, mas estou encontrando o seguinte erro:

```
**Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ t2, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  comprimentos das variáveis diferem (encontradas em 't2')**
```

Segue o script que estou fazendo:

```
scan=(~pib)

#Previsão

tspib = ts(pib[,2],start = c(2002,1), frequency = 12)

tspib

plot(tspib, xlab='Years', ylab = "Pib")

plot(forecast(tspib))

summary(forecast(tspib))

#Regressão

length(tspib)

t=(1:182)

t2=t^2

#Erro aqui

reg=lm(y~t+t2)

summary(reg)
```

O arquivo está em meu PC e é um CSV no seguinte formato (exemplo das 5 primeiras linhas):

```
Data    PIB
2002-01 112374,80
2002-02 111477,10
2002-03 118444,70
2002-04 120385,90
2002-05 123552,50
```

Data está importado como "character" PIB como "numeric".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro está dizendo o problema: as variáveis `t` e `t2` possuem comprimentos diferentes da sua variável resposta.

Veja o erro que aparece nesse código bem simples em que as variáveis possuem comprimentos diferentes.

```
> y = 1:9
> x1 = 1:10
> x2 = 1:10
> lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  O comprimentos das variáveis diferem (encontradas em 'x1')
```

Pelo seu código, `t` e `t2` possuem com certeza o mesmo `lenght`, portanto o problema está entre `t` e a resposta.

Vi que você usa o `lenght(tspib)` e deve ter dado 182 porque você depois fez `t <- 1:182`. Verifique se o `tspib` não tem informações NA, que são excluidas automaticamente quando você ajusta o modelo de regressão.

Comment: Daniel, setei a variável para y = pib$PIB e funcionou. Acho que era este o problema...não havia nada parametrizado para ela. Obrigado!